# hybrid algorithms in energy efficiency for wireless lan

Tags: c#, c++, c, matlab

I looking for hybrid algorithms in energy efficiency for wireless lan. I look an example of this code in c ,cpp, matlab or any other language that I can easily use it.

I already write RSA and ECC algoritm ,but I dont have any idea about how to implement hybrid algoritm,would you help me in this problem?

RSA = Rivest Shamir Adelman
ECC = Elliptic Curve Cryptography

Comment: What is a hybrid algorithm? I know RSA, ECC, C, CPP, MATLAB but I don't understand your question.